# How to show throughput on Allied Telesis switch/router?

Tags: throughput

On Cisco, this can be found using command *#show interface*.

The focus is like below.

> 30 second input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
>
> 30 second output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec

How can the throughput be shown on an Allied Telesis switch/router?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not mentioning any model or software version, I'm just guessing it's AlliedWare Plus. A quick google search gives me http://alliedtelesis.com/manuals/9000V218CLIRevA/ak1027137.html#Rak46367, on which `show platform table port [port] counters` is mentioned as a way to show interface counters.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the model. It is ATI AT-8000S.